# Comparison operator

Tags: comparison

I've build a dropdown box with a list of comparison strings.

```
array(
        'value' => array(
            __( 'Equal', 'js_composer' ) => '=',
            __( 'Does not equal', 'js_composer' ) => '!=',
            __( 'Greater than', 'js_composer' ) => '>',
            __( 'Greater than or equal to', 'js_composer' ) => '>=',                    
            __( 'LIKE', 'js_composer' ) => 'LIKE',
            __( 'NOT LIKE', 'js_composer' ) => 'NOT LIKE',
            __( 'IN', 'js_composer' ) => 'IN',
            // ...etc.
        ),          
    ),  

        if( $meta_query_value !== '' ) {
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'     => $mp_metakey,
                'compare' => $mp_comparison, 
                //'compare' => '>=',
                //'compare' => esc_attr( $mp_comparison ), 
                'value' => $value,
        );
      }
```

I did a `var_dump ($mp_compare);` which showed `string(5) ">="`

And yet no posts are being displayed. When I use `'compare' => '>=',` directly, posts do show up.

I did noticed that when I use 'LIKE', 'NOT LIKE', 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', 'NOT BETWEEN', 'EXISTS posts are showing up.

But when I select the usual operators '=', '!=', '>', '>=', '<', '<=' it's doesn't work.

I also tried using `'compare' => esc_attr( $mp_comparison ),` but that doesn't work either.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Are there actual matches with what you're passing?

Comment: Yes. I've tested it with `'compare' => '>=',` :)

Comment: `string(5) ">="` concerns me. It should be `string(2)` should it not? This feels like you're actually getting `&gt;=` instead of `>=`. If you are doing a var_dump into the basic HTML body, it will encode what you see. View Source or wrap your `var_dump` in a `<pre>` tag, and you should see what's up :).

Comment: Try doing `html_entity_decode($mp_compare)` and see what you get :).

Comment: It's working! `html_entity_decode` did the trick. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string(5) ">="` concerns me. It should be `string(2)` should it not? This feels like you're actually getting `&gt;=` instead of `>=`. If you are doing a `var_dump` into the basic HTML body, it will encode what you see. View Source or wrap your `var_dump` in a `<pre>` tag, and you should see what's up.

Try doing `html_entity_decode($mp_compare)` and see what you get :).

(Moving this to an answer so you can close the question).